# How ToLookup() with multiple indexes?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, lookup

Taking into account the code for C# Console application below,   using

how should I modify it in order to substitute the line:

```
foreach (Product product in productsByCategory[category])
```

by the code line

```
foreach (Product product in productsByCategory[category][Id])
```

?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace myQuestion
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var products = new List<Product>
      {
        new Product { Id = 1, Category = "Garden", Value = 15.0 },
        new Product { Id = 1, Category = "Garden", Value = 40.0 },
        new Product { Id = 3, Category = "Garden", Value = 210.3 },
        new Product { Id = 4, Category = "Pets", Value = 2.1 },
        new Product { Id = 5, Category = "Electronics", Value = 19.95 },
        new Product { Id = 6, Category = "Pets", Value = 21.25 },
        new Product { Id = 7, Category = "Pets", Value = 5.50 },
        new Product { Id = 8, Category = "Garden", Value = 13.0 },
        new Product { Id = 9, Category = "Automotive", Value = 10.0 },
        new Product { Id = 10, Category = "Electronics", Value = 250.0 }
      };


      ILookup<string, Product> productsByCategory = 
              products.ToLookup( p => p.Category);
      string category = "Garden";
      int Id = 1;
      foreach (Product product in productsByCategory[category])
      {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + product);
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

  public sealed class Product
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
      return string.Format("[{0}: {1} - {2}]", Id, Category, Value);
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:**
This is a contrived example with the aim of learning the concepts of C# [ToLookup Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353368.aspx).

As a point of reference, I came to this question after reading [the David Andres' answer to question "What is the point of Lookup?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1403504/2031316):

```
"A Lookup will map to potentially several values.  

Lookup["Smith"]["John"] will be a collection of size one billion."
```

which I'd like to reproduce.

Or I understood it wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure I understand your needs correctly, but why can't you just do:

```
foreach (Product product in productsByCategory[category].Where(x=> x.Id == Id))
```

Or with an anonymous object:

```
var productsByCategory = products.ToLookup(p => new { p.Category, p.Id });
string category = "Groceries";
int Id = 1;
foreach (Product product in productsByCategory[new {Category = category, Id= Id}])
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + product);
}
```

Here is very similar question with additional solution by [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10803833/1193333)

Comment: Could you check "Update:" at the end of my question?

Comment: Saw those code snippets and answers before. Closing it as being confirmed to me that it is impossible to have more than one (custom) index (though composite (from custom class or `Tuple`) on a "lookup"

Answer (score 5):

I've stumbled upon this question, read "closing it as being confirmed to me that it is *impossible*" and made a hefty research on the topic. The closest I could get to was this:

[image: Striving to get a lookup of lookups]

Turns out this can't be done because:

1. There is no constructor for type `Lookup<T, T>`, one can only use `.ToLookup()` LINQ extension function,
2. Said function doesn't have an overload with `resultSelector` (like `.GroupBy()` does) and thus always only returns `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`.

Even if the result of the lookup is just one element (another `Lookup`), there is no possibility to omit the first `IGrouping`. So the call to `.Single()` (or `.First()` or `.ToList()[0]` or `.ElementAt(0)`) is required after each call to "parent" `Lookup`, which is... smelly and desperate.

## But

The same syntax for accessing elements can be instead achieved with nested `Dictionary<T, T>`:

[image: Got it with Dictionaries]

LINQPad C# code uploaded [here](http://share.linqpad.net/wnp8ah.linq).